# Facebook app and Windows Phone 7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I have an app which loads `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=touch&scope=publish_stream` which will ask the user for email and password.

The problem is is that with windows phone 7 the web browser will zoom in when the user taps on one of the fields even if the page fits just right on the browser.

Can I ask the username and password first in the app itself and then send those credentials to the url, or is there a way to disable the zoom in feature.

I tried to log in first with `https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&email={0}&pass={1}` but it tells me I have to log in to do this (log in)

Comment: I wouldn't give your app my fb credentials for you to pass to the browser if it asked. I would go rate it down and post a comment warning people about it too. That totally defeats the purpose of open auth.

Comment: i did feel that this would be bad, but a quirky zoom when entering email + password is almost as bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that.
It would defeat the purpose of Facebook requiring the use of OAuth.

If you use the WebBrowser control inside your app, rather than going out to IE directly this will avoid the issues of the need to pan as the login page will be styled correctly and the control does not allow panning and zooming.

Comment: except that it does zoom in when entering the email or password. which just makes the experience look bad.